# Mapbox animated icon with fixed radius at different zoom levels

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I can create animated pulsating circles and I can create circles that have a specific size, fixed to a map radius no matter the zoom level.

What I'm really struggling with is combining the 2.
Here is what i've got for animation, and for creating the circle limits.
It runs without error, but the circles change size when zooming...

```js
 var framesPerSecond = 15;
 var initialOpacity = 1
 var opacity = initialOpacity;
 var initialRadius = 0;
 var radius = initialRadius;
 var maxRadius = 100;

 map.on('load', function(){

map.addLayer ({
   id: 'area',
   type: 'circle',
   source:{
    type: 'geojson',
    data: {
    type: 'FeatureCollection', features: pointData
   }
  },
  "paint": {
   'circle-opacity': initialOpacity,
   "circle-pitch-alignment": 'map',
   "circle-radius": {
               stops: [
                 [0, radius],
                 [20, radius]
               ],
               base: 2
             },
   "circle-radius-transition": {duration: 0}
      }
 })

 function animateMarker(timestamp) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);

            radius += (maxRadius - radius) / framesPerSecond;
            opacity -= ( .9 / framesPerSecond );

            map.setPaintProperty('area', 'circle-radius', radius);
            map.setPaintProperty('area', 'circle-opacity', opacity);

            if (opacity <= 0) {
                radius = initialRadius;
                opacity = initialOpacity;
            }

        }, 1000 / framesPerSecond);

    }

    // Start the animation.
    animateMarker(0);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks